# Solovay's theorem about decomposition of stationary sets

Tags: set-theory

If $k$ is an uncountable regular cardinal, we want to take a partition of a stationary subset $W\subseteq E_\omega^k=\{\alpha\in k: cf(\alpha)=\omega\}$ in $k$ many stationary sets. 
The proof in *Jech, Set Theory*, Lemma 8.8 pag. 94, concludes with the existence of $k$ disjoint stationary sets $S_\eta$, $\eta<k$, coming from the Fodor's lemma. But why their union should be all $W$?

[image]

Comment: If the union falls short, just add the missing points to one of the sets in the partition arbitrarily (or spread them around if you like); you'll still have a stationary partition.

Comment: Obviously...thanks, i had focused on the main point, that they are $k$...

Comment: But now, i can't see why they are $k$. Can the $\gamma_\eta$'s be bounded or definitely egual to an ordinale less than $k$? They are greater than or equal to the $\eta$'s... Also, can the $S_\eta$ have cardinality $k$?